# Hash - Sha512 only use letters and numbers

Tags: php

Im using hash to create a random string.

```
hash('sha512', uniqid());
```

Will the hash contain only letters and numbers or will other characters be used? If so, how can I limit it so only letters and numbers are used?

Comment: Why didn't you just edit and/or include it in [**your other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26868265/)? Better yet, Google. Two related questions within 30 mins.

Comment: I did google it. Could not find the answer. I find that on SO once a question has been downvoted (previous questions) it fails to get a response, even when edited.

Comment: @N.B. A hash typically hashes to *bits*, base 256. The hexadecimal base 16 representation is *one possible option* to represent the value (arguably the most common option, but nonetheless just one option of many). I'd also suggest that you may want to take a walk around the block. :) Berating users for their Google Foo is not very constructive.

Comment: @deceze - I don't agree, generating laziness is your responsibility. Handing out every piece of obtainable information is just enabling people to be lazy. I am not "berating" anyone, it's a mere fact what I wrote. I admire your energy on SO, but smart people can recognize whether someone is lazy or lacks intellectual capacity. This time is not about intellectual capacity, it's about giving up too soon. Hence the berating. Technically, it is constructive :)

Comment: @N.B. I have given up trying to ascribe or assume traits of a person, for my own personal sanity. As long as the question is well formulated and otherwise within the scope of SO (not a dupe etc.), it's answerable and that's that. Pointing out personal flaws in people hardly got me anywhere at any point, so I don't do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to `hash()` is `$raw_output`. [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) has this to say about this argument:

> `raw_output`
>   When set to `TRUE`, outputs raw binary data. **`FALSE` outputs lowercase hexits.**

While it may be a bit cryptic, "lowercase hexits" means lowercase hexadecimal notation. Hexadecimal notation uses the characters 0-9 and A-F.

So yes, the output will contain only letters and numbers.